# Yacc and Lex "syntax error"

Tags: parsing, ubuntu, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

When I'm trying to check the expression "boolean x;" I'm getting "syntax error" and I can't understand why.
When I'm checking the expression "x = 3;" or "2 = 1;", the abstract syntax tree is generated and no errors are presented.
(I'm not allowed to use anything beside Lex and Yacc in this project and I'm using Ubuntu)

Lex file:

```
%%
[\n\t ]+; 
boolean {return BOOL;}
TRUE {return TRUE;}
FALSE {return FALSE;}
[0-9]+ {return NUM;}
[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]* {return ID;}
. {return yytext[0];}
%%
```

Yacc file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct node{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *token;
    } node;
node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token);
void printtree(node *tree);
#define YYSTYPE struct node *
%}
%start code
%token ID,NUM,TRUE,FALSE,BOOL
%right '='
%%

code:lines{printtree($1); printf("\n");}
lines:calcExp';'|assignExp';'|boolExp ';'{$$ = $1;}
boolExp: boolST id{$$=$2;} 
calcExp: number '+' number {$$ = mknode($1,$3,"+");}
assignExp: id '=' number{$$ = mknode($1,$3,"=");}
boolSt : BOOL;
id : ID {$$ = mknode(0,0,yytext);}
number : NUM{$$ = mknode(0,0,yytext);}

%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
int main (void) {return yyparse();}

node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token){
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(newstr, token);
    newnode->left = left;
    newnode->right = right;
    newnode->token = newstr;
    return newnode;
 }

void printtree(node *tree){
    if (tree->left || tree->right)
        printf("(");
    printf(" %s ", tree->token);
    if(tree->left)
        printtree(tree->left);
    if(tree->right)
        printtree(tree->right);
    if(tree->left || tree->right)
        printf(")");
}
void yyerror (char *s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n",s);}
```

Comment: spelling: is it "bool" or "boolean"?

Comment: oh sorry. I'm trying to check the expression "boolean x;"

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Comment: Start by fixing all of the warnings produced by yacc/bison. The most relevant one is "error: symbol boolST is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules". (If you look closely, the rule `boolSt: BOOL` does not define the symbol  `boolST`.) It's not clear to me why you feel you need a non-terminal here at all; you could have written  `boolExp: BOOL id`. Or, if you had used `%token BOOL "boolean"`, you could use the even more readable `boolExp: "boolean" id`.

Comment: Also, take a look at my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534392/building-and-printing-ast-of-given-input-to-simple-c-compiler#comment82042703_47534392) (which might be to a classmate of yours) and the link I provided to bison's easy-to-use and highly-useful [debugging trace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging).

Comment: I found a solution. In lex file I needed to write the rule [ /t/n]+ with a space between a brascket  and /t. Apparently without a space it doesn't ignore white spaces.

Comment: I added "boolSt" because BOOL didn't worked, so i thought maybe im writing the rules wrong.

Comment: @sophievi: a character class will match a character which is in the list of characters. `[\n\t ]` will match newline, tab or space. So will `[ \n\t]`. But `[\n\t]` only matches newline or tab. Your question has the correct character class, but fails for the reason noted by sepp2k. Nowhere do you indicate that you removed the space in the character class.

Answer (score 2):

The first step to debug syntax errors is to enable `%error-verbose` in the bison file. Now instead of just saying "syntax errors", it tells us there was an unexpected character after the `boolean` keyword when it expected an identifier.

So let's add a print statement to the `.` rule in the lexer that prints the matched character, so that we can see where it produces unexpected characters. Now we see that it prints a space, but spaces should have been ignored, right? So let's look at the rule that's supposed to do that:

```
[\n\t ]+;
```

If your editor has proper syntax highlighting for flex files, the problem should become apparent now: The `;` is seen as part of the rule, not the action. That is, the rule matches white space, followed by a semicolon, instead of just matching white space.

So remove the semicolon and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it didnt work. I removed the semicolon and im getting the same syntax error. When I tried to add %error-verbose, when I typing "yacc project1.y" im getting "yacc: e-line 14 of "project1.y", syntax error %error-verbose"

Comment: I tried to make printf for every token in lex file. For "x=3" it printed id=num; and for "boolean x;" it printed syntax error bool.